# Windows Media Feature Pack

Tags: windows, windows-10

After the new update for Windows 10, my Media Feature Pack is missing.

I can't connect mobile devices to the PC, and I can't use Groove and other applications from the store.

I've installed the Windows Media Feature pack for Windows 10 Pro N (KB3010081), and it does not work.

My PC is a HP 4530s.

How can i choose the correct version of Windows Media Feature pack?

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Have you made any progress?

Comment: yes i made, i already solved the problem ty very much :)

Answer (score 0):

> **After the new update** for Windows 10, my Media Feature Pack is missing.

As you might imagine, this is really the key factor.

The Windows 10 Anniversary Update (a.k.a. Version 1607) will inevitably have some different Microsoft software associated with it.  A quick search will typically reveal what you need:

[Media Feature Pack for N editions of Windows 10 Version 1607](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3133719)